# UpdatePanel Animation only running after Timeout

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, updatepanelanimationexte

Consider the following scenario:

MasterpageFile1:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Frame.master.vb" Inherits="Project.Frame" ClientIDMode="Static" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" name="form1">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BodyPlaceHolder" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Nested Masterpagefile:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" MasterPageFile="/Project/Code/MasterPages/Frame.Master" CodeBehind="Master2.master.vb" Inherits="Project.Master2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <input type="submit" id="btSubmit" runat="server" value="start" class="input" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>CALCULATION RESULT GETS DISPLAYED HERE</div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btSubmit" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <ajaxToolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="upae" runat="server" TargetControlID="up">
        <Animations>
            <OnUpdating>
                <Sequence>
                    <ScriptAction FPS="20" Duration="0.5" script="DoSomething();" />
                </Sequence>
            </OnUpdating>
            <OnUpdated>
                <Parallel>
                    <ScriptAction FPS="20" Duration="0" script="DoSomethingElse();" />
                </Parallel>
            </OnUpdated>
        </Animations>
    </ajaxToolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>
</asp:Content>
```

An ASPX-Page which loads some Styles.

And the follwing jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btSubmit").click();
});
```

This Code triggers the UpdatePanel to Refresh. The OnUpdating Animation is playing, the Server does some calculation stuff and sends the result to the client. The client builds in the result, but the OnUpdatedAnimation nevers plays.

If i change the jQuery code to the follwing, it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#btSubmit").click();
    }, 1500);
});
```

May someone can tell me, why this happens and how to achieve, that the calculation starts when the DOM is ready and not 1.5 seconds later?

Kind Regards,
Sören

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason of such behavior is that not all client objects are initialized when partial postback on `btSubmit` click occured.

Try to use this script (place it after `ScriptManager` control):

```
Sys.Application.add_load(applicationLoadHandler);

function applicationLoadHandler(sender, args) {
     if (args.get_isPartialLoad() !== true) {
          $("#btSubmit").click();
     }
}
```

Comment: Got the same issues here. OnUpdating runs. Result gets inserted, but the OnUpdated Animations aren't running. Console doesn't log any errors or warning. SetTimout solves this issue also, but that's what I want to avoid.